# Is *njwildberger* wrong about area and circumference of a circle?

Tags: calculus, circles

In this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcIbCZR0HbU), **njwildberger** says that the area and circumference of a circle are proof-less theorems. But I heard that we can derive both the area and circumference of a circle using calculus? So are the area and circumference of a circle proof-less theorems?

Comment: I watched very little of the video, but got the impression that he was saying that it is *hard to give rigorous proofs*, and they are *usually taken as fact.* I believe both of these statements. Although Archimedes knew a way to arbitrarily approximate $pi$ in the area-sense, so perhaps that one is not so bad. But defining arc-length, or circumference, is pretty hard.

Comment: I think what he probably means by "proof-less" theorems is just that $\pi$ is *defined* using such formulas i.e. $\pi=C/2r$

Comment: By the way, Wildberger's view of mathematics is a bit different from that of most other mathematicians (it is sometimes called "finitism.")

Comment: @TrevorWilson I'm interested in that, what do you mean? The meaning of "finitism"?

Comment: @SpongeBobSquarePants Basically, it means only accepting the existence of finite objects.  (So, for example, the assertion that there are infinitely many natural numbers would only mean that there is no largest natural number, not that there is an actual set $\mathbb{N}$ which is infinite.)  Some, called ultrafinitists, do not even believe the statement "there is no largest natural number," but I don't know if Wildberger is one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such thing as a proof-less theorem. I just watched the video and he's fast and loose with his terminology. What he means to say is that these theorems are presented to high school students without proof. He doesn't mean there *is no* proof. Then again, lots of things are presented to students without proof early in their education, so that's not really saying much.

Comment: Proof-less theorem: One that we believe to be true from the context but who we can't proove.

Comment: @SpongeBobSquarePants, that's a conjecture.

Comment: No, that's different.

Comment: "In mathematics, a conjecture is an unproven proposition that appears correct" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture

Comment: So what do njwildberger mean by PLT?

Comment: He must have made that term up.

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but I'll throw it out there anyway:

$$A = \pi r^2$$

$$\frac{d}{dr} \pi r^2 = 2\pi r = C$$

Comment: Isn't this an axiom ?

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it is inconsistent with Dr.Wildbergers actual views. Dr.Wildberger doesn't believe there is a rigorous theory of irrational numbers. Therefore there cannot be a proof that $A=\pi r^2$ since $\pi$ hasn't been proven to exist (his opinion not mine).